# Primefaces Push onMessage not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, atmosphere

I am trying out the notify example from http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml

I am using primefaces 5 and glassfish 4.

However, my `onMessage` code is not getting called.

My web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My index.xhtml

```xhtml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" />

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel for="summary" value="Summary: " /> 
                <p:inputText id="summary" value="#{notifyView.summary}" required="true" />

                <p:outputLabel for="detail" value="Detail: " /> 
                <p:inputText id="detail" value="#{notifyView.detail}" required="true" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{notifyView.send}" />
        </h:form>

        <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notify" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
                facesmessage.severity = 'info';

                PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
            }
        </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My NotifyView.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package org.primefaces.showcase.push.notify;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class NotifyView {

    private final static String CHANNEL = "/notify";

    private String summary;

    private String detail;

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }
    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public void send() {
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(summary), StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(detail)));
        System.out.println("Send");
    }
}
```

My NotifyResource.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package org.primefaces.showcase.push.notify;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/notify")
public class NotifyResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        System.out.println("onMessage");
        return message;
    }

}
```

All the files in my library
[image]

I have included a `println("onMessage")` to check whether  @OnMessage in NotifyResource.java is called.
For some reason, the @OnMessage in NotifyResource.java did not get called.

Any idea on why is this so?

Comment: did u found the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Decoder that creates the FaceMessage object :-)

Comment: Hi there. Mind explaining the concept of the decoder? Strange, but the example is not using any decoder. Do you mind providing some codes?

Comment: HI there. I added in a decoder. Like this @OnMessage(decoders = {JSONDecoder.class},encoders = {JSONEncoder.class}) However, it is still not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Move the following *script* into `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
                facesmessage.severity = 'info';

                PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
            }
</script>
```